# How do I get Cython to use an object file?

Tags: python, object, assembly, nasm, cython

I have used the NASM assembler to compile a simple assembly file (code below). I am going to then attempt to take this `.obj` file created, and have Cython link it to a `.pyd` file, so Python can import it. Basically I need a way of telling Cython to include an `.obj` file for use with other Cython / Python code.

First, here is my assembly code:

### myfunc.asm

```
;http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html
global  _myfunc 
section .text
_myfunc:
    push    ebp 
    mov     ebp,esp 
    sub     esp,0x40        ; 64 bytes of local stack space 
    mov     ebx,[ebp+8]     ; first parameter to function
    ; some more code 
    leave
    ret
```

I compile this code by using `nasm -f win32 myfunc.asm`

This gives me `myfunc.obj`, which is what I want to include into a Cython compiled `.pyd`.

I may be completely mislead, and there may be a better method to do this entirely. Is there a simple one liner `extern` that I can do to declare an external object from Cython?

P.S. The label `_myfunc` should be the entry point.

Answer (score 1):

To call the `_myfunc` entry point from Cython, you need to declare it:

```
cdef extern:
    void _myfunc()
```

After that declaration, you may call `_myfunc()` in your Cython module as if it were a Python function. Of course, you will need to link `myfunc.obj` into your `.pyd` as explained in the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463369/1600898).